# Why is there a sandwich attack on the bsc.？How did it happen？

Tags: security

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xeef7b93a99dc9ba7285e495ac3fa61b704762d032669fc038120501d105d26c4
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x36a3b0323312e83a3ce2ce6e0ed390be844c3d12635031417f7fad6eb23766a1
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcdc76170483ba1a1810e8394ec676219d031a8a973c984d2ddecc9fdcd29c650

I know that flashbot can be used to change the transaction position of ethereum, but I don't know how to change it on bsc. Moreover, after the first front running transaction, the victim seems to have exceeded the price slippage, why the transaction is still successful?
This is bothering me, can someone help me solve it?

Answer (score 1):

MEV is clearly happening in BSC network. Private nodes can say whatever because how or who will you prove it to anyway?

Slipagge is not exceeded since the amountoutmin is 3022846044880856256801 and the amountout is 3023148384492376209861 gwei.

Fun part is they are having some kind of outside agreement because the fee is very average. For a direct routing they should be paying more fee. I believe this is to bypass fee burns or links between frontrunner and nodes.
I have tried high gas prices when buying or selling (50 gwei max) but I have never got my transaction mined before currentblock +1 or +2.